# When using exponents the BA II Plus is returning incorrect answers, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: interest-rates

I am using the BA II Plus Texas Instruments calculator.

When I want to calculate an EAR for example, my calculation would be as follows:

(1 + r/m )^m -1 = EAR

So in my calculator, using 5 decimal places I press:

```
1 + ( .03 / 365 ) =
```

This give me the answer:

```
1.00008
```

Then without pressing anything else, I press:

```
y^x 365
```

Which gives me the answer of:

```
1.03045
```

This is the wrong answer since the correct answer to 1.00008^365 is actually 1.02963

Is there something wrong with my calculator? The operations seem to be exactly the same...

Answer (score 1):

The answer as it turns out is quite straight forward.

When using the complete equation, the calculator works out the answer with the full number of decimal places i.e. 1.00008219^365 = 1.03045259